# Why Cached file have high TTFB

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-devtools, performance-testing, web-performance

I'm looking at a waterfall in Chromes Developer tools of several CSS and Javascript files.

When refreshing the page, several of the files load from the browser cache, as expected. These are taking 1ms to load most of the time. However some files, and it seems to be the same offenders each refresh, are taking quite a bit longer. Something between 400ms and 800ms.

The waterfall timeline in Chromes network tab shows that this time is spent in the TTFB (time to first byte) in some cases. This doesn't make any sense to me, if it's getting it from the browser cache and not from the server, why there is a TTFB?

[image]

Can anyone share some light on what's happening here?

Comment: Could it be that scripts earlier up in the waterfall haven't been executed yet? That the script is cached locally, but the DOM itself hasn't yet gotten to that point to render your cached script?

Comment: Yeah, execution is fine, but the main point is if the file is loading from local cache why TTFB is high, it should be ~1ms because the file is loading from cache.

Comment: Have you inspected that JS? Could be making some synchronous operations

Comment: Can you put only that single file on your page and still see if the TTFB is still that large?

Comment: Hi @DavideVitali, yes, that file is not doing any synchronous operations, is an angularjs directive so simple operations. And main issue is that high TTFB is not only for this file, but it is also happening for all the cached files. This is just an example I took